# Is there any super controller or global controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, hmvc

I want to call a function in a controller (say controller_a) from another controller (say controller_b)

Please help me ..

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shared controller functions should usually be in an extended controller class:

```
<?php
/**
 *  File: /application/core/MY_Controller.php
 */
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Prefix with an underscore if you don't want it
     * publicly available through URI-routing
     */
    public function _some_shared_method()
    {
        // some common operation here
    }

}
```

Then, make sure any controller that needs to use this function extends `MY_Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

You would be breaking MVC by calling a controller from another controller. Consider either using a helper, or library for the function you are trying to call.

When controllers call other controllers you're operating in an HMVC framework. See [Modular Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home)

If you're looking for information on controller inheritance, I recommend reading Phil Sturgeon's post on [Keeping It Dry](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY)